# Dataflow refresh never stops

Tags: powerbi

We have a dataflow in our PBI service premium capacity. The target data source is a Snowflake table with about 90M rows. The problem is the refresh never finishes. It can run for days. We can cancel it successfully but it never actually completes, or it doesn't seem to. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: From my experience of working with large TSQL tables, I did face a lot of issues when i brought in the whole fact table (currently 60M+). I think dataflow expects to have the resulting data source query executed and have the resulting table returned within 10 minutes else it will time out.

Comment: Therefore, instead of bringing the whole fact table, I used extensive filtering to bring in the data I need and also aggregated wherever possible so that I can bring in a small table for DF to execute within the limitation.

Comment: On TSQL tables you can easily write SQL queries and only bring in what you need. I guess you probably need to do the same with Snowflake tables, if Snowflake has the option of writing server side queries. I don't have snowflake experience.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Per Microsoft ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#data-refresh)), `On Premium, the maximum refresh duration is 5 hours.` But you're saying this is running for days before you stop it?